# Create dataframe from dataframe rows

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Im trying to save every row from a dataframe in pyspark

I iterate the main dataframe, print the Row content, but it goes to an error I dont know how to resolve

```
columns = ['name', 'job','date']

for row in data_mail_df.collect():
    print(row)
    
    df=spark.createDataFrame(row).toDF(*columns)
    
    df.show()
```

This is what i get:

```
Row(name=u'alex', job=u'admin', date=u'26.04.2021')
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'unicode'>
```

I want to save a dataframe for each row that I iterate

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you going to do with those dataframes created for each row?

Comment: You're also overwriting `df` in each iteration of the loop

Comment: This is probably an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I check if the name of the row exists in bbdd and if not then i save row values into another bbdd

Comment: what is bbdd? @alex

Comment: sorry, it is database. Im checking in one database to insert in another if these values doesnt exist

Comment: Then you should do a join. Do not iterate rows for this purpose.

Comment: But if i wanna save into a file with dataframe format? Just wanna know the error, thanks

Comment: You can get a dataframe using a join

Comment: can you show me an example pls?

Comment: Don't worry, i finally resolved. I code this and it works
`df=spark.createDataFrame([row], [columns])`

Thanks